# Could you tell me this constellation name?

Tags: star, constellations

[image]
Hi Everyone please check this pictures could you tell me this constellation name ?

Comment: You will have to tell us more than just that image. At which time of the day/year, at which location (Longitude, Latitude suffices), in which direction of the sky did you observe this?

Comment: Further, without at least some reference to relative brightnesses, this could be almost any subjective collection of items.

Comment: In addition to the other comments, the size of this "constellation" is important. Is the distance from the top star to the bottom star 1 degree (twice the diameter of the Moon), 10 degrees, or 90 degrees (which would be from the horizon to the zenith -- the point overhead). Also, I assume that the lines you drew are your interpretation of how to connect the stars together. If this is the case, the stars could be from multiple constellations.